# Horizontal rule not displayed in the edit preview pane

Tags: bug, markdown

The horizontal rule is not (always) being displayed in the preview pane, when a question is being edited. I am sure that it used to be.

```
----------
```

---

It appears when the question is first being entered, in the Ask Question window, for example, I can see it now, above this sentence.

I am unable to replicate the issue with this question. However, certainly for longer questions or answers (such as [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/4173/complete-list-of-fasteners-for-the-sintron-kossel#answer-4176) on SE.3D Printing), even though it is visible when simply viewing the question, *if* you edit the question the horizontal rule disappears in the preview pane. Once the edit is saved (and assuming that you have not deleted the horizontal rule's markdown) the horizontal rule will be visible again.

In normal viewing mode:

> [image: Horizontal rule is visible in normal viewing mode]

In preview pane, when a post is being edited:

> [image: Horizontal rule disappears to edit preview pane]

#### Addendum

I have unfortunately edited the post since posting this bug, so the mark down is not the same as above. However, I see the same issue, with the new markdown source.

The markdown that does not show the horizontal bar in the preview pane

```
> thanks.
> 
> james


----------


On a separate note, after examining the guide ([Kossel mini instrution by sintron technology_v2][1]) and the printed parts kit, I came up with an almost complete parts list. The lists relating to the effector and autoprobe mount are missing some screws:
```

Here are new screenshots showing normal view:

> [image: Normal view - bar is shown]

and in preview:

> [image: Preview - no bar]

However, I have just noticed something very odd... This markdown now works fine, and the horizontal bar is shown, in the preview pane:

```
> 
> james

I will update this answer if/when I get a reply



----------


On a separate note, after examining the guide ([Kossel mini instrution by sintron technology_v2][1]) and the printed parts kit, I came up with an almost complete parts list. The lists relating to the effector and autoprobe mount are missing some screws:
```

Here is a screenshot, of it working fine in preview:

> [image: Working in Preview, with the additional line]

To summarise, if I add the following line, the horizontal bar appears in preview, if I remove it the horizontal bar disappears, if I re-add the following line, the horizontal bar reappears, ad infinitum...

```
I will update this answer if/when I get a reply
```

---

On OS X 10.8.5:

- Occurs in Chrome version 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit)
- Seems fine in Safari version 6.2.8 (8537.85.17.9.1)
- Seems fine in Firefox version 48.0.2
- Seems fine in Opera version 37.0.2178.43

Comment: I cannot seem to make this happen (Chrome 58). Not on its own, and not on the answer you linked to (although your screenshots appear to be from an earlier revision, I think this is [the revision your screenshot was from](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/revisions/cec5a18a-3106-4bbf-95ce-cbfe7b702e67/view-source), nothing stands out as odd about the rule in the Markdown there). It would help if you could also include the exact Markdown that was in the editor when the horizontal rule was not being displayed.

Comment: @JasonC - I have updated my post with screen shots and further information. I have also discovered that by adding a line of text the horizontal bar reappears...